# javascript function to strip and parse escape sequence from string in order to colorize the escaped string

Tags: javascript

I am passing a string containing one or more escape sequences to determine a span class to be returned for the escaped text.

Example string passed "/rThis is Red./bThis is blue."

I want to pass the string to a colorize javascript function that will strip out the escape sequences "/r" and "/b" and return:
`<span class="red">This is Red.</span><span class="blue">This is Blue.</span>` 
I have a preset number of classes for the various colors i want to support.

Comment: We can't really help you until you tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/8qqyysLc/1/

```
    var input = "/rThis is Red./bThis is blue.",
    htmlOutput = '';

function updateDisplay() {
    document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = input;    
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlOutput;  
}

function htmlify(input) {
    var cssTypes = ['r','g','b'],
        inputs = input.split('/');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        var cssType = inputs[i][0],
            color,
            htmlString;

        switch(cssType) {
            case 'r':
                color = 'red';
            break;

            case 'b':
                color = 'blue';
            break;     
        }

        var inp = inputs[i] !== '' ? inputs[i].slice(1) : null;

        if (inp) {
            htmlString = "<span class='" + color + "'>" + inp + "</span>";
            htmlOutput += htmlString;
        }
    }     
}

htmlify(input);
updateDisplay();
```